# Solving construction problems?

Tags: geometry, galois-theory, geometric-construction

I recently encountered 'construction problems' in geometry. These were quite new to me and I didn't know the requirements they expected and prerequisites to solve them. I'll explain with an example.

> Let $A, B, C, D$ be four given points on a line $l$. Construct a square such that two of its parallel sides or their extensions go through $A$ and $B$ and the other two sides (or their extensions) go through $C$ and $D$.

[image]

Construct a line $CH$ passing through $C$ such that $\angle BCG = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$. Construct a line $DF$ parallel to $CH$ passing through $D$. Construct a line $BF$ perpendicular to $CH$ and passing through $B$. Construct a line $AH$ through $A$ parallel to $BF$.

The intersection of these four lines forms the required square i.e. $KHGF$ is a square.

Now, to prove that it indeed is a square, construct $BI$ perpendicular to $AH$ through $B$ and $CJ$ perpendicular to $DF$ through $C$.

Let $CD = b$, $AB = a$

Let $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \theta$

$$\angle JDC = \angle GCB = \theta$$

$$FG = JC = CD\cdot\sin\theta = b\sin\theta$$

Similarly,

$$\angle IBA = \angle GCB = \theta$$

$$IB = AB\cdot\cos\theta = a\cos\theta$$

$$\frac{JC}{IB} = \frac{b\sin\theta}{a\cos\theta} = \frac{b}{a}\tan\theta = \frac{b}{a}\cdot \frac{a}{b} = 1$$

$$\implies IB = JC = FG = GH$$

Also, since $CH||DK$, and $BF||AK$, opposite sides are parallel and all angles are right angles. Therefore, $KFGH$ is a square.

Turns out, this quite simple solution is not correct. There is some elaborate procedure of constructions described in my book. I just want to know, what is expected in these sorts of questions and how to approach them.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that you mean compass and straight-edge constructions. These start with two points, 0 and 1, a distance apart. You use a simple set of rules akin to using a compass and an unmarked ruler in order to make lines & new points. It's important for Galois Theory.

Comment: But I might have completely misunderstood your question, in which case, I'm sorry :)

Comment: @Shaun, I think all the constructions Gerard did were ruler-and-compass constructions.

Comment: Gerard, when you say your construction "is not correct", do you mean it doesn't actually construct a square? or do you just mean it's not the same as the construction given in your book? It's quite possible for two different constructions to be correct.

Comment: I know, but I didn't know *he* knew that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: In my book, the initial approach is the same. But after constructing what I did, there are a whole lot of other complicated constructions that achieve the same exact thing. That's why I think my solution is incorrect. It does construct a square, but I think it is not within the definition of a 'construction'.

Comment: If it uses ruler-and-compass, and it constructs a square, then it's a construction. Why your book does something more, I can't say.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with the fact that constructing an angle exactly equal to $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ isn't possible. But that seems to be a stupid reason.

Comment: If you couldn't construct that angle, that would be a valid objection. But you can copy a line segment of length $a$, then raise a perpendicular from one end of it, then mark off length $b$ on that perpendicular, then draw the hypotenuse to get an angle whose tangent is $a/b$, then copy that angle anywhere you like, all with ruler and compass. Besides, you say that the book did the same, so if it counts as a construction in the book, why wouldn't it count as one for you? By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment meant for me, you must include @Gerry in it.